# ¿Cómo ajustar correctamente las líneas de cuadrícula en un gráfico de velas japonesas utilizando MatPlotLibFinance en Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gráficas, visualización-de-datos

Actualmente estoy enfrentando un problema relacionado con la visualización de los datos del eje x en un gráfico de velas japonesas.

En palabras cortas:

> Las líneas de cuadrícula verticales trazadas no se alinean con las
> velas japonesas.
>
> Algunas de estas líneas verticales de cuadrícula están desfasadas por `1` vela después de la primera
> vela japonesa.

Como se puede evidenciar en la gráfica de abajo:

[image: Problem]

La dataframe (llamada `df_trading_pair_date_time_index`) empleada para graficar lo anterior fue la siguiente:

```
                      Open   High    Low  Close   Volume                End Date
Start Date                                                                      
2022-09-11 11:45:00  7.696  7.704  7.695  7.704    267.3 2022-09-11 11:47:59.999
2022-09-11 11:48:00  7.703  7.703  7.695  7.697    537.5 2022-09-11 11:50:59.999
2022-09-11 11:51:00  7.696  7.701  7.695  7.695    292.7 2022-09-11 11:53:59.999
2022-09-11 11:54:00  7.695  7.699  7.695  7.699     64.8 2022-09-11 11:56:59.999
2022-09-11 11:57:00  7.701  7.702  7.701  7.702    101.5 2022-09-11 11:59:59.999
2022-09-11 12:00:00  7.702  7.705  7.680  7.685   4487.0 2022-09-11 12:02:59.999
2022-09-11 12:03:00  7.687  7.691  7.681  7.689   2482.5 2022-09-11 12:05:59.999
2022-09-11 12:06:00  7.691  7.691  7.677  7.682   1074.8 2022-09-11 12:08:59.999
2022-09-11 12:09:00  7.686  7.709  7.686  7.709   1389.5 2022-09-11 12:11:59.999
2022-09-11 12:12:00  7.708  7.708  7.690  7.701   1277.5 2022-09-11 12:14:59.999
2022-09-11 12:15:00  7.698  7.698  7.690  7.695   1655.7 2022-09-11 12:17:59.999
2022-09-11 12:18:00  7.694  7.698  7.692  7.696    576.2 2022-09-11 12:20:59.999
2022-09-11 12:21:00  7.696  7.700  7.694  7.696   1711.3 2022-09-11 12:23:59.999
2022-09-11 12:24:00  7.698  7.703  7.697  7.703   1893.1 2022-09-11 12:26:59.999
2022-09-11 12:27:00  7.701  7.720  7.701  7.717   1256.0 2022-09-11 12:29:59.999
2022-09-11 12:30:00  7.718  7.743  7.718  7.739   5602.6 2022-09-11 12:32:59.999
2022-09-11 12:33:00  7.739  7.744  7.730  7.744    905.6 2022-09-11 12:35:59.999
2022-09-11 12:36:00  7.743  7.780  7.740  7.780   6651.3 2022-09-11 12:38:59.999
2022-09-11 12:39:00  7.780  7.782  7.769  7.772   4478.3 2022-09-11 12:41:59.999
2022-09-11 12:42:00  7.773  7.886  7.773  7.875  30280.6 2022-09-11 12:44:59.999
```

Los tipos de datos de las columnas son los siguientes:

```
Start Date  datetime64[ns]
Open               float64
High               float64
Low                float64
Close              float64
Volume             float64
End Date    datetime64[ns]
```

El código que escribí para graficar lo anterior fue el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf    

trading_pair= "DOTBUSD"

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True
                    )
# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')
```

Entonces, decidí abrir esta pregunta para aprender a ajustar correctamente las líneas de la cuadrícula para el trazado de los datos de velas japonesas, después de leer esta [otra pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610692/i-have-an-alignment-issue-with-the-candlestick-chart-in-matplotlib-which-i-am-bu) Intenté cambiar los valores de `figratio` a `(12,6)` y  `(20,7)` pero eso no resolvió mi problema en absoluto.

Solo desearía que mi gráfico terminara pareciéndose a esto, no necesariamente cubriendo cada vela, pero asegurándose de alinear algunos de los datos del eje x con sus velas correspondientes:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes incluir algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema sin que tengamos que generar una cuenta y sus llaves para la API de binance?

Comment: Hecho, he puesto la `dataframe` usada para graficar y reduje el código al mínimo, aunque al convertir esta dataframe a `diccionario` para ponerlo en el código, me sale un error que dice `Undefined name: 'Timestamp'`, así que no terminé agregando esto en el código, espero que no sea problema para que puedas reproducirlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más sencilla que se me ocurrió de adaptar la solución a tu código es utilizando el argumento `show_nontrading = True` junto con [`matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html) y [`matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_minor_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_minor_locator.html)

Ejemplo completo utilizando tus datos desde el archivo "sample2.csv":

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

trading_pair= "DOTBUSD"

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', index_col = 'Start Date', parse_dates = True)

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up = '#2fc71e', down = '#ed2f1a', inherit = True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style = ['bmh', 'dark_background'], marketcolors = mc, y_on_right = True)    

# Plot it
trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df,
                    figratio = (10, 6),
                    type = "candle",
                    style = s,
                    tight_layout = True,
                    datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig = True,
                    # Activamos nontrading = True
                    show_nontrading = True
                    )
# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","") + "/" + "BUSD"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize = 25, style = 'italic', fontfamily = 'fantasy')

# Elejimos los minutos que serán los "ticks" principales
major_ticks = [45,51,0,9,15,21,30,39]

# Configuramos los "tics" principales
axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=major_ticks))

# Configuramos los "ticks" secundarios cada 3 minutos
axlist[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(range(0,60,3)))

# Configuramos la cuadrícula
axlist[0].grid(visible = True, axis = 'y', which='both')
axlist[0].grid(visible = True,  which='minor')
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Increíble, no tenía ni idea de que se podía personalizar la visualización de datos con esta librería hasta ese punto. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!